# Isotope sorting images by size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I have isotope masonry layout created in my portfolio, and for some reason, all the images are sorted by size. I have 4 'sizes' - big, small, horizontal and vertical. I can control which image gets which class. I also cropped pictures in photoshop, so that width and heights match.

For example my big image is 100x100 px, my small is 50x50 px, and horizontal is 100x50 px, and vertical 50x100 px.

Everything is set up as it should be. I have container, that my isotope function targets, I have classes set up like this

```
.container_fullwidth {
    width: 100.4%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.small{
    width: 19.9%;
}

.medium_vert{
    width: 19.9%;
}

.medium_horiz{
    width: 39.8%;
}

.big{
    width: 39.8%;
}
```

And for some reason, my masonry is very... ordered. First there are small images, then there are vertical and horizontal, and in the end big. The layout is like this:

[image]

I don't know why this is like that? Can't it be a bit more random?

Is there a function in isotope for this? I'm on wordpress, and I have a portfolio plugin enabled. In other instances (no masonry), there is no order to pictures, I haven't set them up like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out by actually sorting it random `sortBy = 'random';`